# Scale rect element from center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm currently using `rect` elements as points on a map and I want to scale their size but the D3 animation always animates the change in width/height starting from the top left corner. Is there a way to scale a rect from the center point so it expands in all directions when animating?

This is the simple D3 code. It is animating the change to width, height rx and ry.

```
.selectAll(".anchor")
    .transition()
    .duration(800)
    .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 50;
    })
    .attr("fill", _graphics.colors.red)
    .attr("stroke", _graphics.colors.charcoal)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("rx", function (d) {
        return 10 / 2
    })
    .attr("ry", function (d) {
        return 10 / 2
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could play with all parameters (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height`). If the `width` is supposed to increase by `100`, then decreasing `x` by `100/2=50` will make the rect appear to grow from its center:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 400);

var data = [
  { x: 50, y: 50, width: 25, height: 50 },
  { x: 180, y: 65, width: 40, height: 20 }
];

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width; })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height; })
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x - 25; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y - 50; })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width + 50; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height + 100; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, you can do that just using the `scale` in the `transform` attribute.

All you need to do is to translate half the width and height while scaling. So, borrowing the code from [Xavier Guilhot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49824230/5768908), all you need is:

```
"translate(" + (-(d.x + d.width / 2) * (factor - 1)) + 
    "," + (-(d.y + d.height / 2) * (factor - 1)) + ") scale(" + factor + ")"
```

Here is the alternative version using the `transform` attribute, and `3` as factor:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 400);

var data = [{
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    width: 25,
    height: 50
  },
  {
    x: 180,
    y: 65,
    width: 40,
    height: 20
  }
];

var factor = 3;

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.width;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.height;
  })
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + (-(d.x + d.width / 2) * (factor - 1)) + "," + (-(d.y + d.height / 2) * (factor - 1)) + ") scale(" + factor + ")"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses from the two professionals.
Maybe I'm not very smart;
I find it challenging to comprehend their code logic,so I wrote a simpler one for better understanding.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 400);

var data = [{
    x: 500,
    y: 50,
    width: 25,
    height: 50
  },
  {
    x: 480,
    y: 65,
    width: 40,
    height: 20
  }
];

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.width;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.height;
  })
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .attr("transform",function(d){
      //We'll switch the element positions between the start and finish of the animation first.
    let result = "translate(" + (d.x + d.width / 2) + "," + (d.y + d.height / 2)+") scale(0)"
    return result;
  })
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {

    return "translate(0,0) scale(1)"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```